# Properties of functions $f(g,\beta\alpha,k+n)=f(g^\alpha,\beta,k)f(g,\alpha,n)$ and outer semi-direct products.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, terminology, functional-equations, semidirect-product

Given a two groups $G, N$ with $N$ possibly abelian. Let $g,\alpha,\beta\in G$ and $x,y\in N$. I'm interested in studying functions $f:G\times G\times N\to G$  that satisfy this functional equation (where $g^\alpha=\alpha g\alpha^{-1}$ and using multiplicative notation).

> $$f(g,\beta\alpha,xy)=f(g^\alpha,\beta,x)f(g,\alpha,y)$$

In general I would like to know if:

> $q1)$ This identity is known, was long investigated, or has a name;
>
> $q2)$ it is possible to derive from this identity some more concrete
> property of $f$ that can help to narrow the possible set of solutions
> of this functional equation;
>
> $q3)$ Is it possible to describe/classify the set of solutions $f\in \mathcal F$?

**Observation 1:** I **want** $G$ to be non-abelian because otherwise we can just take a family of group homomorphisms $\{\phi_g\}_{g\in G}:G\times N\to G$ and set $F(g,\alpha, x):=\phi_g(\alpha,x)$. The set of solutions $f\in \mathcal F$ in the case $G$ is abelian is uninteresting an isomorphic to $ {\rm Hom}(G\times N, G)^G$

*I did put a lot of effort${}^\dagger$ to understand the consequences of this equation but I really don't know what I'm missing.*

In particular, if the previous is not feasible, I'd be happy to know the answer for the special case $N=\mathbb N$.

> $q1^{nat}),\,q2^{nat}),\,q3^{nat})$ All the previous question but for the abelian case $N=\mathbb N$ ($G$ non-abelian).

---

**My attempt${}^\dagger$:**

The first trivial consequence is that $f(g,1_G,1_N)=1_G$. Define $f_g(\alpha,x):=f(g,\alpha,x)$.
I had no luck deriving identities helpful enough to have a clue of what I'm doing: everything I got was the following

- If $g\in Z(G)$ then $f_{g}:G\times N\to G$ is a group homomorphism because for every $\alpha$ we have $g^\alpha=g$.
- For every $g$ the function $\phi_g(x)=f_g(1_G,x)$ is a group homomorphisms $\phi_g:N\to G$;
- In general we have $$f_g(\prod_{i=0}^j\alpha_i,\prod_{i=0}^jx_i)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^jf(g^{\displaystyle \prod_{k=0}^{i-1}\alpha_k},\alpha_i,x_i)\right) f_g(\alpha_0,x_0)$$
- From setting $\alpha=1_G$ I get $f_g(\beta,xy)=f_g(\beta,x)f_g(1_G,y)$ thus $$f_g(\beta,x_0\prod_{i=1}^j x_i)=f_g(\beta,x_0)\prod_{i=1}^j f_g(1_G,x_i)\quad (*)$$ and from that setting $x_0=1_N$ and $\beta=1_G$ one obtains $f_g(1_G,x^j)=f_g(1_g,x)^j$;
- Setting $\beta=1_G$ I get $f_g(\alpha,xy)=f_{g^\alpha}(1_G,x)f_g(\alpha,y)$ thus
  $$f_g(\alpha,(\prod_{i=1}^j y_i) y_0)=\prod_{i=1}^j f_{g^\alpha}(1_G,y_i)\cdot_G f_g(\alpha,y_0) \quad (**)$$
- Merging the two last eq.s $(*)\land (**)$ $$f_g(\beta,x^{j})=f_g(\beta,1_N)f_g(1_G,x)^j
  \\f_g(\alpha,x^{j})=f_{g^\alpha}(1_G,x)^jf_g(\alpha,1_N)$$
  we obtain
  $$f_g(\alpha,1_N)f_g(1_G,x)^j=f_{g^\alpha}(1_G,x)^jf_g(\alpha,1_N)\quad(***)$$ thus $$\boxed{f_{g^\alpha}(1_G,x)=f_g(1_G,x)^{f_g(\alpha,1_N)}}$$

---

**Context**

I'm not sure if I should omit the context where this kind of equation came up because maybe it has nothing to do with the equation itself. The first equation came up, apparently, while enforcing the functoriality conditions of the component on arrows $F_1=f$ of an arbitrary functor $F\in[G^N\times N,G]$. At first I hoped I could parametrize the solution set of the f.eq. using the fact that $[G^N\times N,G]\simeq{\rm End}_{\bf cat}(G^N)$ as categories. I failed to compute one functor from the other establishing the bijection. Anyways establishing this probably wasn't going to answer $q1)$ and $q2)$.

Comment: "$G$ has to be non-abelian" - Probably you mean something else. Of course, $G$ abelian does not produce any contradiction, simply because you did not state anything before. You just wrote down a functional equation.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I may be wrong. What I was trying to convey is that, for my questions 1,2 and 3 to make sense, $G$ must be non-abelian. If it is abelian then the problem is solved. Every family of homomorphisms $G\times N\to G$ will do the job and there is nothing more to understand. I'm sorry If observation 1 was poorly phrased. If instead you can still believe that I'm making a mistake somewhere I hope you can help me improve the question.
Probably I should cut the observation 1 and paste it AFTER the questions. That could make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer; these are actually semi-direct products; but weird ones.

And you are looking for homomorphisms,

$$
f : G \rtimes_{g^\alpha} N \to G\\
$$

Typically one has that $g^\alpha$ would be an isomorphism which depends on $N$ and not $G$. However, (if?) you can take a homomorphism from $N\to G$ this is equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check if this can help. The only thing that doesn't sound right is that $N$, unhappy choice of notation, is not meant to be a normal subgroup of $G$. Those groups are unrelated. So you're suggesting that this is some kind of generalization/weakening of the semi-direct product?

Comment: Yes, this is a weak kind of semi-direct product. I know there's a word for this though; and that your problem is reducible to some kind of semi-direct product construction. I can explain better; when I get more time.